# Grouped by data to detailed data

Tags: python, r, dataframe

****Ilustrating Image has been attached via link****

I have a dataframe which its observations are grouped as follows:

```
column 1 : groups (A,B,C,D....)
column 2 : classification (0,1,2)
column 3 : # of observation per group per classification.
```

I need to turn the data to a detailed one in which the observations will not appear by a group.
example

```
group, class, count
A ,      0 ,    1
A ,      1 ,    2
B ,      0 ,    2
```

I need to change the upper table to:

```
group, class
A ,     0
A ,     1
A ,     1
B ,     0
B ,     0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZIuv.jpg)
any ideas?

eventually it should be 4,000,000 observations so the code should be efficient
tried to run a loop within a loop  (14 hours run created 300,000 rows)

tried to use aggregate (in R), but it didnt work.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post an example of the dataframe you have with expected output and the code you allready have. That will make it easier to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `data.table` approach in R:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt = dt[, .(class = rep(class, count)), by = .(group)]

print(dt)
#    group class
# 1:     A     0
# 2:     A     1
# 3:     A     1
# 4:     B     0
# 5:     B     0
```

Input is:

```
dt = fread("group, class, count
           A ,      0 ,    1
           A ,      1 ,    2
           B ,      0 ,    2")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer tidyverse, here's a solution that does what @docendo did, but slower and less elegantly:

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(group,class) %>% 
  mutate(helper=paste(rep(class,count),collapse=" ")) %>% 
  separate_rows(helper) %>% 
  select(group,class)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   group, class [3]
  group class
* <chr> <int>
1 A         0
2 A         1
3 A         1
4 B         0
5 B         0
```